# Lightsail Domain requests timeout but IP works just fine

Tags: networking, apache2, aws

Previously asked [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/974765/lightsail-instance-requests-time-out-with-domain-name-but-work-with-ip-address) but got no responses and was wondering if any of you would be able to answer my question or experienced similar problems.

I'm able to access my site via its IP address but not via its domain. I'm thinking it is most likely an issue with my Apache setup since I believe everything on the DNS side is configured correctly.

This is my virtual host setup as now:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName [domain].dev

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/bookstack/public/

    <Directory /var/www/bookstack/public/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
        <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
            <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
                Options -MultiViews -Indexes
            </IfModule>

            RewriteEngine On

            # Handle Authorization Header
            RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
            RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

            # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
            RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

            # Handle Front Controller...
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
            RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
        </IfModule>
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog /error.log
    CustomLog /access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

The IP that works is `[IP]` and the domain that should be working is `http://[domain].dev`

Comment: Have you checked your error log for any error messages?

Comment: @vidarlo Yes, there are none.

Comment: That's a bit strange. If you request with curl, it works fine, but not with a browser - it simply times out..

Comment: @vidarlo I'm quite new at doing anything like this, but yeah I'm just as confused. The Lightsail instance is listening on port 80 for HTTP requests so that shouldn't be a problem either. I can SSH into either the IP or domain as well just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/974765/lightsail-instance-requests-time-out-with-domain-name-but-work-with-ip-address/975477#975477)

.dev domains require an SSL certificate to run, and because I did not have one it wouldn't work. Either add an SSL cert or move to a different domain.